# Windows7 and Ubuntu 11.04 in grub

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-11.04

I installed Windows7 on my new netbook (x121e ThinkPad) and then installed Ubtuntu 11.04 afterwards, but grub won't load after startup and windows always starts immediatly. I already did such a setup on my PC successfully, with the only difference that I encrypted my home partition on my netbook. Is there any problem doing this using grub?

Comment: Perhaps post your current GRUB configuration?

Comment: I cannot even figure out where grub is installed, running `grub-probe -t device /boot/grub` just gives back the error `cannot stat 'aufs'`

Comment: and running `sudo fdisk -l` just shows one partition which system is GPT